# the system command opens up a command prompt

Tags: c++, windows

I am currently using the system function in my C++ to load another exe.
I am doing something like this

system("c:\mypath\myfile.exe");

Although the command works fine. I see a black console window along with the newly launched exe. Is there any way to not have that console box show up

Comment: are you waiting for user input after opening that window? can you post the code?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx#CommunityContentHeader: `CreateProcess()` + `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`